# MKAnnotationView Only Rotate the Image property

Tags: mkmapview, cgaffinetransform

I have an MKAnnotationView where I want to rotate the image property only.

If I use the following...

```
        self.image= image;
        [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEG2RAD([item.heading floatValue]))];
```

It rotates the whole annotationView and the subsequent callouts which I do not want.  Is there a way to just rotate the image property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to put the image in a UIImageView, add that as a subview to the MKAnnotationView, and affine that.

If you are targeting iOS 5.0 you could look at [CIAffineTransform](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAffineTransform) but I don't know enough about CoreImage to advise.

Comment: Thanks I did this in the end, performance isn't as bad as I suspected

Comment: I tried this myself, and it works great. However, by tapping the UIImageView, the callout does not pop up. I tried setting userInteractionEnabled=NO;, however that doesn't do it.

Comment: UIImageView userInteractionEnabled is NO by default (unlike other UIViews).  So maybe try setting it YES.  May also need to explicitly detect touches/gestures in the UIImageView, not sure.