# Rotating a display image of MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, ios6, mkmapview, mkannotationview, cgaffinetransform

I'm currently rotating the image property of an MKAnnotationView using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. However, the whole view in this case gets rotated, as well as the callout bubble. So I followed the suggestion within [MKAnnotationView Only Rotate the Image property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401514/mkannotationview-only-rotate-the-image-property/8427625#comment18639397_8427625), and am now creating a UIImageView and adding it as a subview to MKAnnotationView. The image displays and rotates now without issue. However, now the MKAnnotationView doesn't respond to a touch event. I need it to behave just as it did before - on tap/touch it should show the callout bubble. Any ideas what I need to do?

**Initial way I tried (which rotates callout bubble):**

```
MKAnnotationView *aView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Pin"];
aView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapPin.png"];
float newRad = degreesToRadians(degreesToRotate);
[aView setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, newRad)];
```

**Using a UIImageView and adding as a subview:**

```
MKAnnotationView *aView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Pin"];
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapPin.png"]];
iv.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[aView addSubview:iv];
aView.canShowCallout = YES;
```

**Update**
I tried to add a gesture recognizer, though it doesn't work. imageTapped method doesn't get called when I tap on the UIImageView within the MKAnnotationView on the map. This is within the method: - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation

```
MKAnnotationView *aView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Pin"];

UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapPin.png"]];
iv.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
iv.exclusiveTouch = NO;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
[iv addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

[aView addSubview:iv];
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the answers here and none of them completely worked, but I found a different solution that did!

I believe the easiest way to do this is to rotate the `UIImage` itself before setting the `image` property of the `MKAnnotationView`.  If you have hundreds and hundreds of annotations this may perform poorly, but if you just need to rotate a couple things (like in my case), it works just fine.

I found a helper class to rotate UIImages, and then simply used that to rotate the UIImage before setting the `image` property of `MKAnnotationView`.

Helper class is here: http://www.catamount.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=967

Now, to rotate the UIImage property of the MKAnnotationView on the map without sacrificing the callout bubble, do the following:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)pMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MyAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MyAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"WayPoint"]; 

    annotationView.image = [annotationView.image imageRotatedByDegrees:45.0];

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return annotationView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is now a very old question, but I recently encountered this problem and it had a very simple solution. The only reason the annotation view becomes unclickable when using an image view is that the MKAnnotationView has a size of (0,0) when no image is set. The image view is visible because the annotation view doesn't clip to bounds. All I had to do was set the frame on the annotation view to make it clickable again.

```
MKAnnotationView *aView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation  reuseIdentifier:@"Pin"];
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapPin.png"]];
[aView addSubview:iv];
annotationView.frame = (CGRect) {
            .origin = CGPointZero,
            .size = iv.frame.size
        };
aView.canShowCallout = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this to the image view to see if you can pass its touch event to the annotation.

```
//Do this before you add the imageview as a subview
self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];



- (void) imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
    MKAnnotationView * annotationView =  (MKAnnotationView *)tapGesture.view.superview;
    if (annotationView.selected) {
        [annotationView setSelected:NO animated:YES];
    } else {
        [annotationView setSelected:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this a few days ago with no luck, I'll try it again this weekend and see if I have any luck.

Comment: Give the way that i wrote it a shot, it should work remember to add the gesture recognizer to the image view and set the image view user interaction enabled to yes.

Comment: The touch gesture event doesn't fire... I'll post what I tried in the question.

Comment: Can you please try setting exclusiveTouch to no instead of yes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Swift extension method to help. The most popular answer results in a blurry image using the linked helper library.

```
extension UIImage {

    func rotated(degrees degrees : Int) -> UIImage {
        // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
        let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width, self.size.height))
        let rotation = CGFloat(degrees) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180
        let t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);
        rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
        let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rotatedSize, false, 0.0);
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, rotation);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(-self.size.width / 2, -self.size.height / 2, self.size.width, self.size.height), self.CGImage);
        let rotatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return rotatedImage;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "my_image")!.rotated(degrees: 45)
```

Answer (score -2):

// Just set the image property before adding the subview and it works like charm

```
MKAnnotationView *aView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Pin"];
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapPin.png"]];

aView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapPin.png"];   //   just this line

[aView addSubview:iv];
aView.canShowCallout = YES;
```